# Syntax issue in Tamir SharpSsh RunCommand

Tags: c#, sql, ssh, syntax-error

I am trying to write the following line of code in my program :

```
xxxx.RunCommand("echo "select count(*) from TABLE_NAME;"|sqlplus DB Connection");
```

Now as I understand RunCommand's syntax is RunCommand("Unix Command");

But in my program I need to use multiple " ". Please suggest what would be the correct code here. Sorry for this basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean about escaping them, you need to use `\"` instead.

```
xxxx.RunCommand("echo \"select count(*) from TABLE_NAME;\"|sqlplus DB Connection");
```

Or use verbatim string literal with doubling them.

```
xxxx.RunCommand(@"echo ""select count(*) from TABLE_NAME;""|sqlplus DB Connection");
```

- [Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)